# (db) Add another syntax in WHERE/SET(UPDATE) part?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

Overview: this is a code where a student can sign up for courses he want to read. **He should only be accepted into one course, not more**(*this is where I got problem with*). Although the student can search up to 3 courses at same time by priority selection 1-3.

If a courses is full then students get a queue-index, starting from 1 and up. Once there's a free spot in the course(*that's where this syntax below is being used, looping for each free spot in a course*), the student with queue-index 1 hit 0 and he's accepted into the course.

```
  cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Register]  
                     SET QueueIndex = QueueIndex - 1,  
                     Accepted = IIF(QueueIndex = 1, 1, 0)  
                     WHERE QueueIndex > 0 AND CourseID = @cid;";
```

However I don't know how to improve this syntax and implement a checker in this syntax if that student is already accepted in any other courses. If he already is, then he should be NOT be accepted(*and set his queue-index to 0 so he's no longer in queue, and accepted is still false*) and check for the next student instead. I don't know how to improve this syntax.

In the db-table, I'm **using CourseID**, **StudentID**, **Accepted(bool)**, Selection(for 1-3 course choices, *not important here*),  **QueueIndex(int)**

I would like to implement some kind of.. If that current student with QueueIndex = 1, AND if any of his/StudentID choices/selections is Accepted = true  THEN QueueIndex = 0 and set Accepted = false, so that current choice is no longer relevant since he's already accepted.

Or like `AND (if (StudentID with QueueIndex= 1 have any (accepted=true) in any choices/CourseID)) = false`  in WHERE? Like another syntax in WHERE part or something.

EDIT: I was thinking something like this in `WHERE`-part

`AND  0 = (SELECT COUNT(Accepted) FROM [Register] WHERE StudentID = (SELECT StudentID FROM [Register] WHERE QueueIndex = 1 AND CourseID = @cid)) AND Accepted = True`

**EDIT2: ctumturk made me realize that I asked wrong question.  I should simply set the student `QueueIndex = 0` for all course she/he selected once he get accepted.**

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly but in case I did, why don't you set  any `QueueIndex = 0` of a student as soon as he/she accepted a course which is available? So if a student selects a course which is available for selection, the student is removed from any other queue.

Comment: Do you have access to the `@StudentId` in your query, or just the `@CourseID`?

Comment: @ctumturk I do have that method once they are in action, if they get accepted, every queueindex sets to 0. HOWEVER, if he wasnt accepted, then he can get accepted later via this method once there's a free spot. That's why I have to fix this part.

Comment: @Jamiec If I have access to these property in table? Yes, if you mean in my C#code, well I can get access to @ studentId via a syntax where queueindex is 1 and CourseID = @ courseID

Comment: @ctumturk EDIT: wait a moment.. You got a point, that would fix this syntax as well. I asked wrong question.. It should be.. How do I set every `QueueIndex = 0` as soon as he/she get accepted into available course, as you said. Is it possible to add something in SET part like `SET (QueueIndex = 0 WHERE StudentID = @ studentID)` ?

Comment: I guess you set `accepted = true` for corresponding course and student. Your query possible have something like `WHERE studentID = @sid AND couseID = @cid`. In that case you can use a second query to set all `queryindex` values to 0 for corresponding student. It can look like what you have lately posted. I believe you execute your queries in an `EventHandler`. First execute first query to assign the course to the student than clear all queryindex's for that studentID.